# Create Custom Woocommerce Text Fields and display on frontend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-field-type

I wanted to create Additional WooCommerce Custom Fields that I can display on my Archive Page and Single Product Page.
So I followed this Tutorial— ( https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-product-fields-woocommerce) — and this— https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTDE6pJjOKs —– and this —- (https://wpsimplehacks.com/how-to-create-custom-fields-in-wordpress)
But these Tutorials are too complex. I have been able to follow them and get my Custom Field on my Backend as you can see here— (https://prnt.sc/VzBQDq-jp0PY)
The challenge I’m facing now is that I’ve not been able to translate that Data to show on the Frontend. I’ve been struggling with it for 6 Days now.
The thing is that I did get the Data to show on the Frontend through this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTDE6pJjOKs) —– and this —- (https://wpsimplehacks.com/how-to-create-custom-fields-in-wordpress) ——- but it scattered the entire Page Layout.
Now, I couldn’t tell what part of the code is causing that conflict.
What I am asking for now, is someone that can help me make sense of the Codes here-- (https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-product-fields-woocommerce/)
Then create it for only Text Field, and show how to output it on the frontend, on the Single Product Page to look like this-- https://prnt.sc/6W_S1w1BQlRc
Regards.

Comment: Instead of sharing links, please share the code you're using to add & save fields in the backend and what code you've tried so far to show fields on the frontend so that your code could be fixed by experts.

Comment: I do not know which of the Code is correct, and where the problem of the Code is. So I added the links to show where the codes are, and hoped that someone willing to help can see all the codes from there, and help me compile them into something sensible, meaningful, useful and manageable.